# Use of IF statement in Header file

Tags: php, get-template-part

I have a custom page template created. When I load my page, it shows the header logo of the mainpage but what I want to achieve is for each custom template created, I want it to only show its own logo.

This is the bit of the header code that calls the logo.php file:

```
<?php get_template_part('parts/logo', 'top') ?>
```

This is what I have tried but not working

```
<?php if ( is_page('custom-page')) {
    get_template_part ('parts/custom-logo', 'top');
} else {
    get_template_part('parts/logo', 'top');
} ?>
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is the custom-logo-top.php file defined??
Seems you are not using the `get_template_part` the right way. Please check the [`Codex`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) for details

Comment: hmm... hang on a minute, you might be right. I will take a look at this soon. Thanks for the response

Answer (score 1):

As Maruti Mohanty mentioned you might not be using [get_template_part](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) in the correct way. The first argument is the slug name for the generic template. The second argument is the name of the specialized template. So currently your code is doing the following:

- On the page that has the 'custom-page' slug, display the template part named `custom-logo-top.php`.
- If that file doesn't exist then just display the generic template part called `custom-logo.php`

I'd probably name your template parts 'logo.php' and 'logo-custom.php'. It's worth having a look through the Twenty Fourteen theme that comes with Wordpress as well as the codex whenever you're unsure of anything.

Comment: yes he was right, I followed the same format the Theme owner wrote and that mislead me. So I had to remove top from mine and replaced it with logo since my file name was custom-logo.php and not custom-logo-top.php